# Run bash script instead of a single file executes two

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

results=($(mysql --user xxx -pxxxxx asterisk -Bse "SELECT id,did From global_did WHERE status='no' LIMIT 1 ;"))

cnt=${#results[@]}
for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++ ))
do

cat << EOFTEST1 > /etc/asterisk/script/$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))-255621067201
Channel: Local/255621067201@dialer
MaxRetries: 0
WaitTime: 30
Context: informer
Extension: 255621067201
Callerid: ${results[1]}
Account: Tanzania
Priority: 1

EOFTEST1

UPDATED=${results[0]}
mysql --user=xxxx --password=xxxx asterisk -Bse "UPDATE global_did SET status='yes' WHERE id='${UPDATED}';"
```

I set it to have a random number **$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))** when executing it, it generates two files instead of one,what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$cnt` is 2, so the `for` loop executes 2 times, and creates a different file each time.

Comment: Why do you have the `for` loop if you don't want to create multiple files?

Comment: And, occasionally you'll overwrite the first file with the second run.

Comment: You seem to expect `cnt` to be the number of rows returned by the query. But since the query returns two columns in each row, `cnt` is twice the number of rows.

Comment: Just get rid of the loop and it will work as you expect.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that what the OP wants if for the output of every iteration of the loop to go to the file.  That is, `for (( ..)); do cat << ...; done > /etc/asterisk/scripts/$((1 + RANDOM %1000))-...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is executing once for each column being returned by the query. Since the query returns two columns, `$cnt` is `2`, and you execute the code twice, and get two files. Just get rid of the loop.

If you want to allow the query to return more than one row, and perform the loop for each row, you should increment `$i` by 2, not 1, and use `$i` in the array indexes rather than hard-coding `1` and `2`.

```
for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i+=2 ))
do

    cat << EOFTEST1 > /etc/asterisk/script/$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))-255621067201
Channel: Local/255621067201@dialer
MaxRetries: 0
WaitTime: 30
Context: informer
Extension: 255621067201
Callerid: ${results[$i+1]}
Account: Tanzania
Priority: 1

EOFTEST1

    UPDATED=${results[$i]}
    mysql --user=xxxx --password=xxxx asterisk -Bse "UPDATE global_did SET status='yes' WHERE id='${UPDATED}';"
done
```

Comment: there is no guarantee that random will return you distinct values!